# Script creating multiple indexes

Tags: postgresql

How can i create a Postgresql script to create multiple indexes?

I've a list of 'CREATE INDEX' statements and don't want to execute the one by one.
So it would be nice to have a script for this job.

Postgresql 9.1

Comment: You can run them as bundle of commands... As one Query...

Comment: Can you explain me how. How to seperate the commands ? Is it possible to add them in a file (one command per line) and use psql -f <filename> ?

Comment: each command should be ";" separated.

Comment: Already tried to seperate them bij ';' but that doesn't work. Only the first one executes.

Comment: For others who also struggle with this. After some trail and error, this works for me:  psql -d <db_name> -f <file_name> One command per line in file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command

```
  psql -f file_path db_name
```